# SSLHandshake failed with Error code -9801 on Alamofire 3.1.2, XCode 7.1, iOS 9

Tags: swift, ssl, ios9, alamofire

I did the following upgrades to my Swift project

1. iOS 9, XCode 7.1, El Captain
2. Alamofire 1.3 -> 3.1.2

I get the following error while connecting to a self signed (test) web service.

**Error Message**

> 2015-11-12 21:46:13.045 [72695:5258083] CFNetwork SSLHandshake failed
>   (-9801) 2015-11-12 21:46:13.046 [72695:5258083]
>   NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed
>   (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9801) 2015-11-12 21:46:13.051 [Error]
>   [DeviceInfo.swift:277] generateUserToken > Error while processing
>   generateUserToken() : Optional(Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain
>   Code=-1200 "An SSL error has occurred and a secure connection to the
>   server cannot be made." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801,
>   NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server
>   anyway?, NSUnderlyingError=0x7ffa99a0b8c0 {Error
>   Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1200 "(null)"
>   UserInfo={_kCFStreamPropertySSLClientCertificateState=0,
>   _kCFNetworkCFStreamSSLErrorOriginalValue=-9801, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9801}}, NSLocalizedDescription=An SSL error has occurred and a secure
>   connection to the server cannot be made.,

I have implemented the below code to disable SSL validation as per https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#security

```
class CustomServerTrustPolicyManager: ServerTrustPolicyManager {
    override func serverTrustPolicyForHost(host: String) -> ServerTrustPolicy? {
        var policy: ServerTrustPolicy?
        policy = ServerTrustPolicy.DisableEvaluation
        return policy
    }
}

public class NetworkManager {

    static let sharedInstace = NetworkManager()

    let defaultManager : Manager = {

        let serverTrustPolicies: [String: ServerTrustPolicy] = [
            "myservice.com": .DisableEvaluation
        ]

        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = Alamofire.Manager.defaultHTTPHeaders

        return Alamofire.Manager(
            configuration: configuration,
            serverTrustPolicyManager: CustomServerTrustPolicyManager(policies: serverTrustPolicies)
        )

    }()

}
```

Also, I have added the below entry in info.plist but no luck.

```
<dict>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>myservice.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <false/>
                <key>NSThirdPartyExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
                <string>TLSv1.1</string>
                <key>NSRequiresCertificateTransparency</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</dict>
```

Has anyone successfully connected self signed service using Alamofire & iOS9? Please advice.